# Is it bad practice to have parameters the same name as a variable in the outer scope?

Tags: javascript, function, state, svelte

I've run into this enough that I thought I'd ask: is it bad to have parameters the same name as a variable in the outer scope. This happens alot when I write in React or Svelte where the state of the component is the name I want to use in the function. Below is some code I just wrote in Svelte where I run into this. I get that is works, but I don't really like it. I think it would also break if I needed to modify the function to use the state in the outer scope. Any pointers would be helpful. Thank you.

```js
// global state named `files`
let files: File[] = [];

// also wanted to use `files` as a param name but couldn't
function handleFilesChange(uploadedFiles: File[]) {
    files = sortFilesChronologically(files, "desc");
}

// using `files` as a param name
function sortFilesChronologically(files: File[], direction: "asc" | "desc" = "asc") {
    return [...files].sort((file1, file2) => {
        const file1Time = new Date(file1.lastModified).getTime();
        const file2Time = new Date(file2.lastModified).getTime();
        const dirModifier = direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
        return dirModifier * (file1Time - file2Time);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow Use a different name, or put the function in a different file

Comment: I suppose this is somewhat a matter of opinion, but it's called "shadowing", and it's generally frowned upon since it makes it confusing which variable is being referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can potentially cause unnecessary confusion and errors, but tooling can help prevent this from happening at all or differentiate state from arguments. ESLint was already mentioned in that regard.

If a function does not rely on state reactivity, you can consider to extract it to a separate file where the shadowing would not happen.

Using prefixes like you did with `handleFilesChange` to separate the names is always an option as well. I often use `new`, `old`, `current` and the like.

---

> I think it would also break if I needed to modify the function to use the state in the outer scope

You would just have to rename the function parameter first, which should be simple refactoring operation.

Comment: Great. It seems like using simple adjective descriptors will work well in the case where it makes sense to keep the function in that file. Thanks!